# ASP.NET C# - Setting up Forms Authentication Security

Tags: asp.net, security, active-directory, forms-authentication

What's the easiest way to make Forms Authentication functional? Do I need to setup IIS/Active Directory? If so, how would you code that?

I was looking at this tutorial but it is a bit long, hard, and confusing: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

Here's my web.config info:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OleConnectionStringSource" connectionString="Data Source=dev-sql01; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;Integrated Security=false"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="OleConnectionStringTarget" connectionString="Data Source=dev-sql01; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;Integrated Security=false"
     providerName="System.Data.OleDb;" />
    <add name="PriceFinderConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=dev-sql01; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PriceFinderConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=dev-sql01;Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <!--run aspnet_regsql.exe on alg-sql01 when I get write access to alg-sql01, add Data Source=alg-sql01;User ID=PriceFinderUser;Password=speg#st!9e8_#as; 
        delete Integrated Security=SSPI; line -->

</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

  <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="OleConnectionStringSource"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />  
  </providers>
</membership> 

<profile>
```

Thanks! :)

```
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" /> 
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: the link is leading to "how I create a custom webservice" ... webservices have nothing todo with membership and authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've set the authentication mode to Forms, you need to handle the FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie and SetAuthCookie.

You may want to check out a tutorial such as: [An overview of forms authentication (VB)](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link!

Comment: I thought the use of cookies was antiquated and poor form?